# Remove duplicate rows query result except for one in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates

How would I delete all duplicate month from a Microsoft SQL Server Table?

For example, with the following syntax I just created:

```
SELECT * FROM Cash WHERE Id = '2' AND TransactionDate between '2014/07/01' AND '2015/02/28'
```

and the query result is:

```
+----+-------------------------+
|Id  | TransactionDate         |
+----+-------------------------+
| 2  | 2014-07-22 00:00:00.000 |
| 2  | 2014-08-09 00:00:00.000 |
| 2  | 2014-08-25 00:00:00.000 |
| 2  | 2014-08-29 00:00:00.000 |
| 2  | 2015-01-27 00:00:00.000 |
| 2  | 2015-01-28 00:00:00.000 |
+----+-------------------------+
```

How would I remove duplicates month which is only return any 1 value for any 1 month each, like this result:

```
+----+-------------------------+
|Id  | TransactionDate         |
+----+-------------------------+
| 2  | 2014-07-22 00:00:00.000 |
| 2  | 2014-08-09 00:00:00.000 |
| 2  | 2015-01-27 00:00:00.000 |
+----+-------------------------+
```

Comment: you want to delete or just not select them?

Comment: just not select them so there will be no query result from duplicate month.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the help of [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

This will tell you which are the rows you are going to keep

```
SELECT id,transactionDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY YEAR(TransactionDate ),MONTH(TransactionDate ) ORDER BY TransactionDate ) firstTrans
FROM Cash 
WHERE Id = '2' AND 
TransactionDate between '2014/07/01' AND '2015/02/28'
```

You can delete the other rows with a CTE.

```
with myCTE (id,transactionDate, firstTrans) AS (
 SELECT id,transactionDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY YEAR(TransactionDate ),MONTH(TransactionDate ) ORDER BY TransactionDate ) firstTrans
    FROM Cash 
    WHERE Id = '2' AND 
    TransactionDate between '2014/07/01' AND '2015/02/28'
)
delete from myCTE where firstTrans <> 1
```

Will only keep one transaction for each month of each year.

**EDIT:**

filter by the row_number and will only return the rows you want

```
 select id, transactionDate from (SELECT id,transactionDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY YEAR(TransactionDate ),MONTH(TransactionDate ) ORDER BY TransactionDate ) firstTrans
    FROM Cash 
    WHERE Id = '2' AND 
    TransactionDate between '2014/07/01' AND '2015/02/28') where firstTrans = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Select only the first row per month

```
SELECT *
FROM Cash c
WHERE c.Id = '2' 
AND c.TransactionDate between '2014/07/01' AND '2015/02/28'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
                   FROM Cash c2
                   WHERE c2.Id = c.Id
                   AND YEAR(c2.TransactionDate) * 100 + MONTH(c2.TransactionDate) = YEAR(c.TransactionDate) * 100 + MONTH(c.TransactionDate)
                   AND c2.TransactionDate < c.TransactionDate
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run this query you will get the highest Id for each month in each year.

> ```
> SELECT MAX(<IdColumn>) AS Id, YEAR(<DateColumn>) AS YE, MONTH(<DateColumn>) AS MO FROM <YourTable>
> GROUP BY YEAR(<DateColumn>), MONTH(<DateColumn>)
> ```

If needed, for example, you can late delete rows that their Id is not in this query.